# How to run a command through a text file with different number of arguments on each line

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a text file similar to the one below (much longer). I'm trying to do a lookup for each of these IP addresses using the `host` command. Do you know how I could do this in the order of the text file (entire first line, then the second line, etc.)?

I tried using this, but it did not execute correctly:

```
while read in; do host "$in"; done < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Input text file:

```
10.10.999.200 10.11.223.334 10.55.555.555
10.12.238.222 10.52.212.212
10.12.238.222 10.14.217.232
10.23.212.212 10.19.301.305 10.12.345.678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the spaces to newlines and pipe each IP to `xargs` to process.

```
tr ' ' '\n' < inputfile.txt | xargs -IX host X > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it this way:

```
cat file | while read line   
do   
    echo "$line"  
done
```

This way can see line by line. However, if your file is huge, it will take long time because every time you read file in shell, program open, read, close file. In such case you have to use AWK